# MYSQL PHP Subtotal with column edit

Tags: php, mysql

Struggling with MySQL query.. time to ask for help.
I am trying to get sub totals for amount of time, problem is that I can't get the other columns to show the way I want. Coding with PHP.

Plus the table values, there is also hidden ID value that is different for every row.

table i have:
[image: table i have]

Doing query as:

```
SELECT id, date, project, SUM(duration) AS duration FROM mytable GROUP BY date desc, id with rollup"
```

I get it right, but I want to get rid of the project name and make the column show like "total duration:"
So I don't want to make subtotal for project, just for the date. but I want to get rid of project name in total row.

Output that I get:
[image: Output that I get]

Output that I want:
[image: Output that I want]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: group by desc is dropped in version 8 so you may as well fix now.

Comment: please add data always as text and produce a [mre]

Comment: Have you read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put an example in [phpize](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql80/22ac61f634ddaf8bb9a7466ec0e7b912/php/php8/b50d3adbf0efd25753030d529afa8592):

To the example, a table creation:

```
create table mytable(id int, date datetime, project varchar(255), Duration int);
insert into mytable values(1, "2022-01-30", "Project 1", 3), 
                       (2, "2022-01-30", "Project 1", 2),
                       (3, "2022-01-30", "Project 2", 4),
                       (4, "2022-01-29", "Project 3", 4),
                       (5, "2022-01-28", "Project 3", 3),
                       (6, "2022-01-28", "Project 3", 2);
```

In php, the rows loop sum a variable and, on each date change, it inserts one line with a subtotal:

```
   <?php
use Carbon\Carbon;

$now = Carbon::now()->format('d/m/Y');

printf("Today is %s\nCurrent PHP version: %s \n\n", $now, phpversion());

$query = "SELECT VERSION() as version;";

// Select using Laravel
$version = $db::select($db::raw("SELECT VERSION() as version;"));
printf('DB version (Laravel Query Builder): %s ' . PHP_EOL, $version[0]->version);

$sql = "SELECT id, date, project, duration FROM mytable order by date desc";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$last_date = null;
$subtotal = 0;
$total = 0;
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    printf("Date                Project   Duration\n");
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      if ($last_date == null){
         $last_date = $row["date"];
      }
      
    if( $last_date != $row["date"] )
    {
        printf("------------------------------------- \n");
        printf("%s Total Hours  %d Hours \n", $last_date, $subtotal);
        printf("------------------------------------- \n");
        $last_date = $row["date"];
        $subtotal = 0;
    }     
      
    printf( "%s %s    %d Hours \n",
                 $row["date"],
                 $row["project"],
                 $row["duration"]
          );
    $subtotal += $row["duration"];
    $total += $row["duration"];
  }
        printf("------------------------------------- \n");
        printf("%s Total Hours  %d Hours \n", $last_date, $subtotal);
        printf("                    Total Hours %d Hours \n", $total);
        printf("------------------------------------- \n"); 
    
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
```